# Web View Horizontal Scrolling issues above kitkat

Tags: android, android-webview

I call an Url in Webview which show horizontal scroll grid it scrolls smoothly in Kitkat but not scroll smoothly in other android versions.If We call this URL android browser it scroll smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Disable [hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) in your activity like this:

```
<activity android:name="your.package.Activity"

            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

            ...  />
```